# How to debug when /etc/sudoers is not working?

Tags: security, sudo

Is it possible to debug when `sudoers` is seemingly not working?

I'm trying to give a user called `power` access rights to shut down a Synology NAS from `ssh` without sudo.

Here is my one and only record for the `power` user at the very end of the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
power ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/sbin/shutdown*
```

When I log in as `power` and issue the following command, it does not work:

```
power@synology:/$ shutdown -h now
shutdown: Need to be root
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common misconception of the `NOPASSWD` clause in sudo. You still need to add `sudo` before your command or else it won't be processed correctly. A better solution would be to give your user an alias to shutdown - `alias shutdown='sudo shutdown'` - so on the surface it will look the same.

Comment: Thank you, absolutely right! It works now!